# Spricht man über ein Mädchen/eine Frau mittels „sie“ oder „es“?

Tags: word-usage, pronoun, gender

> **Diese Frage wurde auch hier (auf Englisch) beantwortet:**
>   *[Can ‘sie’ be used to refer to ‘Mädchen’?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/33000/9551)*

Wenn man über ein Mädchen oder über eine Frau spricht, spricht man dann von *ihm* oder von *ihr*?

> Das Mädchen ist jung. Es ist schön. Sie ist schön.

Ich tendiere ja zu der Bezeichnung *sie*, habe aber nun schon des Öfteren auch mitbekommen, dass ein *es* benutzt wurde. Gibt es da einen Unterschied zwischen einem Mädchen und einer Frau?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Das grammatikalisch korrekte Personalpronomen für *Mädchen* ist **es**, da "Mädchen" ein Nomen mit sächlichem Geschlecht (Neutrum) ist. Wörter, die Verkleinerungsformen sind, die mit *-lein* oder *-chen* gebildet werden, sind immer sächlich.

Andere Beispiele:

> Das Bürschlein ist sehr flink. Es klettert im Nu auf einen Baum.
> Das Mütterchen wohnt im alten Haus. Ich gehe es morgen besuchen.

In der Umgangssprache wird sich allerdings kaum jemand daran stoßen, wenn man die jeweils "natürlichen" Geschlechter (er/sie) verwendet.

Zu **Frau**: Da man "die Frau" sagt, verwendet man in diesem Fall *sie*.

Comment: +1 Ergänzend würde ich sagen, dass umgangssprachlich vielleicht sogar das natürliche Geschlecht bevorzugt wird.  [Für Fortgeschrittene: Die Reihenfolge im Satzbau und die Situation spielen ebenfalls eine Rolle, z.B. wenn über eine bestimmte Person gesagt wird: "*Sie* ist ein junges Mädchen." (Außer naturlich in Situationen, wenn man z.B. fragt, wer an die Tür geklopft hat: "*Es* ist ein junges Mädchen." - allerdings hat das eigentlich nichts mit dem Geschlecht des Objekts zu tun.)]

Comment: Die Grimms haben das _es_ im 19. Jahrhundert etwa für _das Aschenputtel_ und _das S(ch)neewittchen_ noch im kompletten Text durchgezogen. Im 21. Jahrhundert wirkt grammatische Genuskongruenz statt semantische Sexuskongruenz höchstens innerhalb desselben Satzes noch natürlich.

Answer (score 16):

Beide Personalpronomina sind im Beispiel korrekt. In einem längeren Text (und ohne Verwechslungsmöglichkeiten) ist es eher üblich, zum natürlichen Geschlecht zu wechseln, innerhalb desselben Satzes ist es hingegen notwendig, beim grammatikalischen Geschlecht zu bleiben. Im obigen Beispiel von einem Satz mit Mädchen und einem Satz, der sich auf das Mädchen bezieht, ist beides gebräuchlich.

Hier handelt es sich im übrigen nicht um "Anrede" oder "ansprechen", denn diese Worte bezeichnen immer einen Satz in der 2. Person, also du, Sie oder ihr. Früher hat es in manchen seltenen Situationen als formelle Anrede auch die 3. Person gegeben, das wird aber überhaupt nicht mehr verwendet.

Answer (score 4):

In Low German dialects this conflict is resolved by rendering *all* females gender-neutral: "Dem Susi sein Vadder hat ihm dat verboten.  Et kann net komme." — "Susan's father has prohibited it to do that.  It cannot come."

In colloquial High German, there is a tendency to flip to female gender that is stronger the larger the distance between "Mädchen" and the referring pronoun gets.