# Which grammatical gender would I use for a masculine noun with reference to a woman?

Tags: gender, pronoun, inflection

Given that "Schatz" is a masculine word, I would use masculine modifiers with it, such as "der".

But suppose I were using "Schatz" to refer to a woman I was dating.

Would I then refer to "*mein* Schatz" because "Schatz" is masculine?

Would I say "*meine* Schatz" because my date is feminine?

Or should I refrain from using masculine words to refer to female dates?

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2731/spricht-man-über-ein-mädchen-eine-frau-mittels-sie-oder-es?rq=1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### mein Schatz

Articles do never change. And it is not uncommon at all to say "mein Schatz" to a woman. Compare to the use of "das Mädchen" :)

Comment: _Mein_ is a possessive pronoun, not an article.

Comment: Some people tend to use the diminutive "Schatzi" which turns it neuter ("das Schatzi"). If the reason behind this is to not use a masculine description for their beloved wife, I cannot say.

Comment: @npst: To me as a native speaker it seems weird, that "Schatzi" has a gender at all. But  I guess it has to have one...

Comment: Mein Joe, meine Joe. Mein Jean, meine Jean. Bei Namen kann sich der Artikel ändern, auch wenn es ein Possesivpronomen ist. :)

Comment: Weil Namen keinen Artikel haben :)

Answer (score 6):

Oh it is quite common to use *Schatz* for your girlfriend or wife / children.

You would always refer to her as *mein Schatz* as the word is masculine.

When this masculine word refers to a female it is still masculine, 
and thus requires masculine declension of adverbs and adjectives.

for the last. *Schatz* is more common with Girlfriend / Wife and i would deem it inappropriate for a date, as it suggests a deeper or even binding relationship when used as calling name.

*Schatz* is also sometimes used to thank someone you are close with,
even if it's not a binding relationship: *"Bist ein Schatz, Danke"*

Comment: When I say "date" in this context, I'm not referring to a casual date. More like someone in whom I would have a serious interest.

Comment: @TomAu in general you still wouldn't use *Schatz*. this word is usually reserved for your partner in a "binding" relationship, not someone you are interested in ;)

Comment: *"Sie sind ein Schatz!"* is quite possible too (but should not be used in a professional setting, as it may be felt as discriminating).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is always „mein Schatz“, grammatical gender trumps natural gender. It could only become confusing if you introduced her into your speech as „mein Schatz“ in the first sentence and would then continue to talk about her in the next sentence, because grammar would dictate that you then use „er“. Usually people will avoid this and switch to „sie“.

The same thing happens if someone is, say in a legal document, referred to as „die Person“. They would, regardless of natural gender, then have to be referred to as „sie“.

Comment: But when talking about "die Person", I'd argue most writers will not try and avoid "sie" (as opposed to the first example with "Schatz ... er"). In fact, I have no problem imagining a sentence like "Die Zielperson betritt den Platz. Wir nehmen sie jetzt fest." and picturing the target person as a guy, which is slightly different from my perception of "Mein Schatz hilft mir immer. Er ist jetzt hinter der Bühne.", where I find it somewhat hard to imagine the speaker is talking about a woman.