# Can ‘sie’ be used to refer to ‘Mädchen’?

Tags: pronoun, gender

> **This question also has an answer here (in German):**
>   *[Spricht man über ein Mädchen/eine Frau mittels „sie“ oder „es“?](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/2731/9551)*

I’ve come across this text:

> Ein Mädchen sitzt am Fenster. ***Sie*** hat lange Haare.

Shouldn’t it be ***es*** instead?

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange! I linked to the question and answer in German. Your question is still no duplicate as it is OK to ask in German or English.

Comment: Actually I had a hard time trying to comprehend the answers in German, as I'm still a beginner. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The grammatically correct personal pronoun is "es", because "Mädchen" as it is a neuter substanctive. Words with -lein or -chen are diminutive forms of words and always neuter.

Other examples:

> Das Bürschlein ist sehr flink. Es klettert im Nu auf einen Baum.
>
> Das Mütterchen wohnt im alten Haus. Ich gehe es morgen besuchen.

However, it is common to use the biological gender of the person (er/sie), in colloquial speech or in longer texts (without the danger of misunderstandings).

This might be compared to the use of pronounce "he/she" for beloved pets instead of the pronoun "it".

Answer (score -6):

Yes, it should be **es**. But we don't know the context. It would be inappropiate if **Mädchen** had been used merily as an affectionate form for *woman* and the next sentence would be something like this:

> Ein Mädchen saß am Fenster. **Sie** hatte lange Haare. Ich fühlte mich sofort zu **ihr** hingezogen.

That one is okay, because it is clear it isn't really a *Mädchen* but a young *Frau*.

The following would let people think of Nabokov's *Lolita*.

> Ein Mädchen saß am Fenster. **Es** hatte lange Haare. Ich fühlte mich sofort zu **ihm** hingezogen.

Comment: Thanks. I had no knowledge of such use of the word 'Mädchen'.

Comment: This answer is nonsense. The correct answer was given by Phira here: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2731/spricht-man-%c3%bcber-ein-m%c3%a4dchen-eine-frau-mittels-sie-oder-es?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Could you please explain why this answer is *nonsense* to you, when it says exactly the same as the answer you linked to?

Comment: Nope. it's perfectly ok to refer to a young woman as "Mädchen" + "es" or a female child as "Mädchen" + "sie". It is merely a question of style, apparently there is a trend to use the pronoun according to natural gender instead of grammatical gender.

Comment: I gave you a fishy look if you talked as in the second example.

Comment: Can we agree to disagree? For me, combining "Mädchen + es" is always perfectly grammatical; being attracted to a child (and possibly acting on it) is disgusting independent of the pronoun used.

Comment: Can we agree that both is correct (mainly because it's *my* opinion)? *Das Mädchen ging über die Straße - [Sie|Es] trug ein blaues Kleid und gelbe Turnschuhe.* Sounds both perfectly alright to me without expressing affection or not.

Comment: @tofro I very much agree - as I tried to explain above.

Comment: @Stephie The choice might be a matter of distance - I would never refer to my daughter as "es", to any other girl very well.

Comment: @tofro likewise I can't think of a feasible example when I would refer to mine as a "Mädchen" unless I use the term as a qualifier for her behaviour or other pattern. ("Ein richtiges Mädchen"). But that discussion would be better placed in [chat], I guess.

Comment: -1. I think, this example is not well chosen. It would never assume that "das Mächen" was used as an affectionate for a woman in the sentence of the question. And I "Ich fühlte mich sofort zu ihr/ihm hingezogen." both makes me think of a lolita girl

Comment: Yet another falsification of facts in an accepted answer.

Comment: @Iris: that example is deliberately chosen that way. It should be *es* gramatically. That's what I've written in the first sentence. However, *sie* is also acceptable and may be even better, depending on the context. I don't get what's so hard to understand about it.

Comment: @Janka I don’t (like all the others here) see **any** difference in implied meaning or usage between your two examples. **Neither** makes any explicit or implicit statement about the girl’s age. **Both** can be interpreted as a young lady or a little girl. Most importantly, **both** make me immediately jump to a conclusion involving Nabukov’s *Lolita.*

Comment: I think you should read more *regular* love novels then.