# Eine männliche Giraffe und [seine|ihre] Kälber?

Tags: gender, possessive-pronoun

Heute habe ich diesen Satz auf meinem Windows 10 Lock Screen gelesen:

> Interaktionen zwischen einer männlichen Giraffe und seinen Kälbern sind relativ selten.

Ist dieser Satz grammatikalisch korrekt, oder müsste es nicht eher "ihren Kälbern" heißen, da das Substantiv "die Giraffe" feminin ist?

Hat hier das biologische Geschlecht oder der grammatikalische Genus Vorrang bei der Wahl des (Possesiv-)Pronomens?

Comment: Ähnliche [Frage](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/2731/1696) mit *Mädchen* und *es* oder *sie*.

Comment: Männliche Giraffen sind auch Giraffenbullen. Und dann würde man `Interaktionen zwischen einem Giraffenbullen und seinen Kälbern sind relativ selten`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es müsste *ihren Kälbern* heißen, da das grammatikalische Geschlecht gilt. Es wird nicht aus *die Giraffe* plötzlich *der Giraffe*, nur weil wir von einem Männchen sprechen. Das Adjektiv *männlich* hat hier ebensowenig Einfluss wie andere Adjektive, die nicht das Geschlecht definieren (z.B. groß, schön, dick, etc.).

Ähnliches gilt beispielsweise auch für *Mädchen*. Obwohl es sich bei einem Mädchen unzweifelhaft um ein weibliches Wesen handelt, heißt es

> Das Mädchen spielt mit seinen Puppen

und nicht

> Das Mädchen spielt mit ihren Puppen

Comment: Klar, stimmt. An das Beispiel "Mädchen" habe ich gar nicht gedacht... Microsoft hat mich ganz verwirrt ;-)

Comment: Allerdings wird die Variante, das Pronomen am Sexus statt am Genus auszurichten, zunehmend üblicher (siehe z. B. [Elke Donalies in grammis 2.0](http://hypermedia.ids-mannheim.de/call/public/fragen.ansicht?v_kat=&v_id=31)). Und wenn man davon ausgeht, dass in einer lebendigen Sprache der Gebrauch die Regel bestimmt, sind beide Varianten richtig. Da es in dem Giraffen-Beispiel offenbar spezifisch um die Verhaltensunterschiede zwischen männlichen und weiblichen Elterntieren geht, halte ich die Variante mit "seinen Kälbern" für in jedem Fall vertretbar.

Comment: Tue ich nicht. Denn dann musst Du bitte auch von *Der männliche Giraffe* sprechen. Ich vertrete übrigens auch nicht die Ansicht, dass der Gebrauch die Regel bestimmt. Das führt nämlich zum Einen dazu, dass jeder sprechen darf, wie er will und zum anderen, dass niemand eine Sprache sinnvoll lernen kann.

Comment: »Das Mädchen spielt mit ihren Puppen« ist für mich ein grammatikalisch völlig korrekter Satz. Hier hat das biologische Geschlecht das grammatikalische übertrumpft. Allerdings bezweifle ich, dass das bei der männlichen Giraffe so auch schon funktioniert.

Comment: *Das Mädchen spielt mit ihren Puppen* spielt für mich in einer ähnlichen Liga wie *Die USA hat einen neuen Präsidenten*, *Kann ich noch was Cola?*, *Eine Millionen Euro* oder *Eine Million Euro wurden geboten*.