# Why "seinem" Mörder and not something with "ihr-"?

Tags: pronoun, gender

In the following sentence, why "seinem" Mörder and not something with "ihr-"? ihrem, maybe? Since we are talking about a girl here, how did we get seinem? Thank you.

> Schwer zu sagen, ob das Mädchen in diesem Moment überhaupt begriff, was geschehen war. Aber es drehte sich vermutlich um und sah seinem Mörder in die Augen.

Comment: See also this (in German): https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2731/spricht-man-%c3%bcber-ein-m%c3%a4dchen-eine-frau-mittels-sie-oder-es