# "Es" und "ihres" im gleichen Satz im Bezug auf "das Mädchen" benutzt

Tags: pronoun, gender

In Ein Landarzt, schreibt Kafka:

> »Hilf ihm«, sagte ich, und das willige Mädchen eilte, dem Knecht das
> Geschirr des Wagens zu reichen. Doch kaum war es bei ihm, umfaßt es
> der Knecht und schlägt sein Gesicht an ihres. Es schreit auf...

Ich weiß, dass wenn man grammatikalisch korrekt schreiben oder sprechen will, muss man die neutralen Pronomen benutzen, es/sein/usw., um sich auf "das Mädchen," was ein neutrales Nomen ist, zu beziehen. [Ich habe aber auch erfahren](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/2732/50482), dass es in der Umgangssprache ein bisschen Spielraum gibt, wo man manchmal trotz allem "sie" benutzen darf. Aber hier steht in einem einzelnen Satz von Kafka eine Kombination von beiden Formen - "es" und dann am Ende "ihres." Ich vermute, dass Kafka wohl die zwei Gesichter unterscheiden wollte, und es vielleicht komisch oder verwirrend wirken würde, wenn er "schlägt sein Gesicht an seines" geschrieben hätte. Stimmt das?

Wenn ich bisher recht verstehe, ist meine Frage: klingt für euch dieser Satz klar und natürlich, angesichts dieses Problems, also der möglichen Verwirrung, die entstehen würde, wenn man "sein" quasi wiederholen würde? Oder ist eine solche Mischung vielleicht veraltet oder einfach seltsam, Kafkas Stil entsprechend? Gibt es heutzutage eine natürlichere Möglichkeit, mit diesem Problem umzugehen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die Freiheit, semantischen Bezug zu nehmen, ist nicht nur in der Umgangssprache gegeben - jedenfalls macht das die Duden-Grammatik nicht ausdrücklich deutlich.

Ich stimme deiner Vermutung zu, dass es hier hilfreich ist, Verwirrung zu vermeiden, also klar zu machen, dass das Gesicht des Mädchens gemeint ist.

Du könntest Du das Gesicht am Ende explizit erwähnen: "an das Gesicht des Mädchens". Durchweg das biologische Geschlecht zu nutzen gilt wohl als schlechter Stil - man vermeidet es eher. (Siehe Kommentare)

Der Satz ist für mich natürlich und unauffällig.
Nur das Akkusativpronomen würde ich hinter das Subjekt stellen: "umfasst der Knecht es".

Comment: "das Mädchen" ist deshalb neutral, weil es ein Diminutiv ist (von "die Maid") und diese ALLE neutral sind. Das hatten wir schon x-mal.

Comment: @bakunin Inwiefern ist Dein Kommentar hier relevant?

Comment: Weil du schriebst: "Man könnte durchweg das Geschlecht nach dem Sinn wählen, und so den Wechsel zwischen Neutrum und Femininum vermeiden." Die Relevanz besteht darin, daß mein Kommentar eine direkte Antwort auf diese Einlassung war. Das, was Du oben vorschlägst, geht halt nicht, weil "das Mädchen" biologisch zwar immer weiblich aber grammatikalisch immer neutral sein wird.

Comment: @bakunin Kafka scheint aber das Gegenteil zu beweisen.

Comment: @bakunin Bitte schlage "Constructio ad sensum" nach.

Comment: @tofro: ~Seufz~ ja, natürlich geht das *punktuell*. Es ging um das *durchweg*, das ich bezweifelt habe. Anders ausgedrückt: ein grammatikalisches Prinzip, daß, ungeachtet des grammatikalischen Geschlechts, *immer* das biologische Geschlecht zu verwenden ist, wird sich nicht finden lassen: "Den Ochsen bringe ich in den Stall und dann binde ich es an" ??

Comment: @bakunin Achso. So eine Empfehlung habe ich leider noch nirgends gesehen, deshalb kam es mir richtig vor. Wo finde ich diese Empfehlung? Ich habe die Antwort editiert. Danke für die Korrektur.

Comment: *ein grammatikalisches Prinzip, daß, ungeachtet des grammatikalischen Geschlechts, immer das biologische Geschlecht zu verwenden ist, wird sich nicht finden lassen*. Das hat hier niemand behauptet. Man kann es verwenden, ohne dass das auffallen würde.